# Get all Last values from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json

My question, what is the best way to get all the last values from javascript object.
Example: Given any object (Must accept any object), but for an example:

```
const obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-37.3159",
    }
  }
}
```

And have a function to get all the last values:

```
console.log( getAllLastValues(obj) );
```

And the expected result is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "lat": "-37.3159"
}
```

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with this function?

Comment: I'm building a reusable component for data table. And a user to use the component must pass the data. And If the user not specifies the columns. I want to put all columns in the data table. And for that I only want the last values to work in the table. @Sergey Denisov if you have another idea to do this please tell me.

Comment: @Jared I can do this function with Object.keys() and testing if the typeof is a function or object and try one step further until I get a string or number. But as I said is for a reusable component. I'm not an expert. So I want to have an expert opinion about that. And I search about that on google and I didn't found anything. And I need a optimized function.

Comment: Optimized in what sense?

Comment: @tozaraburo In time consuming. Like people want to use a reusable component, or like to production business application. Wants something fast. And is that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive function for this that uses `reduce()`

```js
const obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "address": {
    "street": function() {
      return 'Function works'
    },
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-37.3159",
    }
  }
}

function getLast(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (typeof data[e] == 'object' && data[e] !== "function") Object.assign(r, getLast(data[e]))
    else if (typeof data[e] === "function") r[e] = data[e]()
    else r[e] = data[e]
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(getLast(obj))
```

Update: More complex data structure.

```js
const obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "address": {
    "street": function() {
      return {
        lorem: 'ipsum',
        another: function() {
          return 'one'
        },
        test: 'Test'
      }
    },
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-37.3159",
    }
  }
}

function getLast(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (typeof data[e] == 'object' && data[e] !== "function") {
      Object.assign(r, getLast(data[e]))
    } else if (typeof data[e] === "function") {
      if (typeof data[e]() === 'object') Object.assign(r, getLast(data[e]()))
      else r[e] = data[e]()
    } else {
      r[e] = data[e]
    }
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getLast(obj), 0, 4))
```

Comment: Yes, this function works with objects that does not have a function. Great idea, I didn't thought to use reduce.

Comment: @Elias Pinheiro  `JSON.stringify` was just for demo try again https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1596/

Comment: Yes I saw that, I'm trying instead to have a function have the returned value. In final stay `"street": "Functions works"` . And the function can return a object or another function.

Comment: Check out update, it runs function and returns value.

Comment: But if the function return another function, or return an object. I'm trying to do this too. It's a little hard. Must be recursive that part too. But thank you very much. You're awesome.

Comment: Give me an example.

Comment: Now it's perfect. Exactly what I want. Thank you.